# Best Data Structure for Returning Multiple Values from Static Method

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am writing a class that has a static method that my colleagues will call in their client code.  The method iterates over a bunch of files, changing their contents and their names.  What I would like to do is return a single 'success/fail' value, and then a list (not necessarily a formal 'List') of the changes that were made to the files.

**What I have tried**

My current implementation is to build a TreeMap, where the key is an integer and the first value (at position 0) is 'success' or 'fail'.  The remaining values (1 through N) are an ordered list of the changes that were made.

**My question**

If you were my (esteemed) colleague, would this returned data structure be a good idea to you?  Is there something more elegant, a design pattern that fits this case?

I would like to keep my methods static (per my company's standard for utilities), so I would like to avoid custom data structures/objects.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Keeping the methods static and creating a custom data structure/object to return are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to think about what your clients would do with the information beyond the "success/fail" status.  If you do need more capability, then consider returning an object (a sub-class of your class, or your class), that has methods to make the inquiries your clients may need.  That way the internal structure you use can be hidden (or changed as needed) but client interface would not have to change.  Clients would see something like:

```
Transform result = Transform.fixFiles(...);

if (result.isSuccessful()) {
xxxx
}

changes = result.getChangeList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't embed the status in a data structure consisting entirely of completely different things.

Sounds like a normal tuple, e.g., a status, and a value object representing whatever. Generics are often used to represent things like this.

The "best" answer, however, depends on things we don't know, like:

- How do other libraries in your environment do it?
- What constitutes a "failure"?
- Would an exception make more sense?
- Do you need to record all failures like each of the files for which renaming failed, etc?

Answer (score 1):

In a case where you want to return multiple values or a complex object like this, a custom data structure would fit quite well. When you return a map, it's not very clear what is in that map. A map should be used when you really have key/value pairs, not an ordered list. If you have an ordered list, use a list.

There's no reason you can't have a custom data structure that is returned by a static method. And then you can add clear methods to it that indicate what you're actually returning. Favor readability of your code, not about how to best hack existing data structures to fit your need.

My two cents anyway.